# Recursive longest common subsequence, incorrect printing

Tags: c, algorithm, lcs

First I'd like to excuse for probably pathetic question. I am writing recursive longest common subsequence program. It usually works fine, but if there are two (or more) equally long results it gets wild. (e.g. jdbac,abjac should give: "bac, jac" but instead it prints jac,jac,bac );
I am using two 2D arrays, first with "way", second with lcs lengths.
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define max 99
int way[max][max];
int n, m;
int PrintLCD(char * subseq1, char * subseq2, int i, int j) {
  //printf("%d %d \n",i,j);
  //printf("%d \n",way[i][j]);
  //if(i==0 || j==0)return 0;
  if (way[i][j] == 1) {
    PrintLCD(subseq1, subseq2, i - 1, j - 1);
    printf("%c", subseq1[i]);
  }
  if (way[i][j] == 2) {
    PrintLCD(subseq1, subseq2, i - 1, j);
  }
  if (way[i][j] == 3) {
    PrintLCD(subseq1, subseq2, i, j - 1);
  }
  if (way[i][j] == 4) {
    //printf("\n %d",way[i][j]);
    way[i][j] = 2;
    PrintLCD(subseq1, subseq2, n - 1, m - 1);
    printf("\n");
    PrintLCD(subseq1, subseq2, i, j - 1);
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {

  /*
    a   b   d   c
    0   0   0   0
  a0    1   1   1   1
  b0    1   2   2   2
  c0    1   2   2   3
  d0    1   2   3   3

  1 3   3   3
  2 1   3   3
  2 2   4   1
  2 2   1   4   

  */

  //1-skos 2-gora 3-lewo 4-gora/lewo
  //1-\ 2-up 3-left 4-both
  int i, j;
  char A[15], B[15];
  char subseq1[16] = {'~'};
  char subseq2[16] = {'~'};
  printf("Podaj pierwszy ciag: ");
  scanf("%s", A);
  printf("\nPodaj drugi ciag: ");
  scanf("%s", B);
  printf("\n");
  strcat(subseq1, A);
  strcat(subseq2, B);
  m = strlen(subseq1);
  n = strlen(subseq2);
  int C[n][m];
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++) C[i][0] = 0;
  for (j = 1; j < n; j++) C[0][j] = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < m; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (subseq1[i] == subseq2[j]) {
        C[i][j] = C[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
        way[i][j] = 1;
      } else if (C[i - 1][j] >= C[i][j - 1]) {
        C[i][j] = C[i - 1][j];
        if (C[i - 1][j] == C[i][j - 1]) {
          way[i][j] = 4;
        } else {
          way[i][j] = 2;
        }
      } else {
        C[i][j] = C[i][j - 1];
        way[i][j] = 3;
      }
    }
  }
  /*************
  rekurencja(i.j)
  jezeli w way ij:
  4 rekurencja i-1j
  rekurencja ij-1
  3 rekurencja i-1j
  2 rekurencja ij-1
  1 printf("%c",subseq1[i]);
  ***********
  */
  printf("Najdluzszy podciag to: ");
  PrintLCD(subseq1, subseq2, n - 1, m - 1);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Not a pathetic question (better than many first-timers anyway), but maybe you could describe what you mean exactly by "longest common subsequence" and give a couple of examples of program inputs and expected outputs (I mean according to the usual definition of longest-common subsequence, for the input `jdbac,abjac` the output should be `ac`, right?).

Comment: @jdehesa you are confusing substring (consecutive characters in order) and subsequence (characters in order but don't have to be consecutive). So [jac, bac] are the correct answers for [jdbac, abjac].

Comment: @maraca I see, you're right, thanks (and hence I was thinking of the longest-common substring problem). I have the impression "subsequence" is frequently misused instead of "substring" in programming (although maybe it feels weird to talk about "substrings" for non-text data, e.g. a sequence of numbers or objects... I'd probably end up saying "contiguous subsequence", even though it's the same but longer).

Comment: What does LCD stand for?

Comment: I see the problem, but there is no easy fix for it. You basically have to see that when you do a split if way is 4 and end up on the same 1 next, then it will be the same subsequence. Same with unused letters at the start, there are several ways through them, all representing the same subsequence.

Comment: Oh! I see now, You are right. I have plenty 4's on the way, that's probably why it prints more results than necessary. But how to fix it then?